# How to pass array of any object type to sort routine

Tags: arrays, sorting, delphi

I have an efficient sorting routine for arrays that I would like to be applicable to a more general class of arrays. The code below demonstrates the idea:

```
type
  TtestRec     = class
    index      : integer;
    rndm       : integer;
    constructor  create(indx,aRandomInt : integer);
  end;

  TtestRecArray= array of TtestRec;

var
  base         : TtestRecArray;

constructor TtestRec.create(indx,aRandomInt : integer);
begin
  index:=indx;
  rndm:=aRandomInt;
end;

function makeArray(N,m : integer) : TtestRecArray;
var k : integer;
begin
  setLength(result,N);
  for k:=0 to N-1 do result[k]:=TtestRec.Create(k,random(m));
end;

procedure sortTestRecs(var A : array of TtestRec; compare : TlistSortCompare);
begin
 // may change order of elements but not modify elements itself
end;

procedure sortGeneral(var A : array of Tobject; compare : TlistSortCompare);
begin
 // should be same as above but applicable to other types of records
end;

function compareRecs(left,right : pointer) : integer;
begin
  result:=TtestRec(left).rndm-TtestRec(right).rndm;
  if result=0
     then result:=TtestRec(left).index-TtestRec(right).index
end;

begin
  base:=makeArray(100,100);
  sortTestRecs(base,compareRecs);
  sortGeneral(base,compareRecs);   // Incompatible types: 'array of TObject' and 'TtestRecArray'
end.
```

The argument to `sortGeneral`could be any array with elements derived from Tobject. After all, it is just an array of pointers. The functional relevance is contained in the `compareRecs` function. But the definition of `sortGeneral` does not allow it to be called with anything other than `array of Tobject`. How can I make this work (without generics)?

Comment: Look into [Overloading Procedures and Functions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions). You will also have to submit different compare functions.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but still important: You shouldn't use subtraction to compare integers.

Comment: Regarding the actual question, it's not quite clear to me what you are trying to achieve. A sorting function needs to consider the structure of the data. You could use untyped pointer or `TObject` arrays everywhere and unsafe casts (if you know what you are doing). If you want to add some type safety on a higher level you can still use the array cast I mentioned in my comment to your previous question. `sortGeneral(TArray<TObject>(base),compareRecs);`. You haven't told us the Delphi version you are using, but if you are on a pre-generics one, u need 2 dcl a `type TObjArray = array of TObject`.

Comment: @Andreas YES! thank you so much and sorry that I didn't understand your earlier respons. `procedure sortGeneral(var A:TArray<TObject>,compare:TlistSortCompare)` will accept arrays of any object type.

Comment: Why don't you want to use generics? Removing type safety won't make your sorting algorithm faster.

Comment: TArray<TObject> *is* using generics. Just saying...